# Modified shortest path algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph, depth-first-search, shortest-path

I've been looking for solution but got stuck.

I need to find shortest path in undirected graph. As input I got set of undirected edges `(x,y,p)` where `x` and `y` are nodes and `p` which is weight of the edge between `x` and `y`.

The length of a path is defined as the sum of of absolute differences between adjacent edges of each node.

Example edges:

```
1 2 1
1 3 5
2 4 5
3 4 5
4 6 2
```

There are multiple paths from `1` to `6`:

```
1 -> 2 -> 4 -> 6   weight = |5 - 1| + |2 - 5| = 7
1 -> 3 -> 4 -> 6   weight = |5 - 5| + |2 - 5| = 3
```

Thus the shortest path has length `3`, which should be the output of the algorithm.

Comment: Are the weights on the nodes or the edges? It sounds like you have node weights and use absolute difference as edge weights. In that case you can use Dijkstra.

Comment: Weights are on the edges, in excercise it is defined that to compute weight of node f.e y where there is a path x->y->z then weight of the y  =|xy -yz| (xy is weight of the edge between x and y nddes)

Comment: But then you have positive weights. You can just transform the graph prior to finding the shortest path.

Comment: I said that i don't know if weights are positive :) I don't know anything about weights and cycles

Comment: You use the absolute difference to find the cost of a path, so you have non-negative weights since the absolute difference is non-negative.

Comment: Yeah i see that, but what about cycles ? Is Dijkstra appropriate for it ?

Comment: If you have non-negative weights, then any cycle will just increase (or not change) the cost of the path and so will be a worse path than any already found.

Comment: But computed weight is defined for each node. And if there are few path including the node so that node consists some different weights. When i use dijkstra i choose the lowest weight on next edge let's say. Now i dont know what to choose because weight is weirdly computed for node

Comment: How many nodes do you have?

Comment: In the example you have given, is there a path from node 1 to 2? And what would its weight be?

Comment: @Bartosz I can answer this question, but I will not do so because it doesn't contain all necessary information. Please update the question so that it's more understandable what your goal is. Currently it's a real mess and doesn't incorporate additional information you gave in your comments. Also pleaye include size restrictions such as maximum number of nodes and edges.

Comment: Number of nodes is unknown (yes I know that I didn't help but I don't know it either). There is a path from 1 to 2 and oposite as well (from 2 to 1). Both paths have exact same weights.@ Niklas B there no known size restrictions. Problem is very badly described but I won't get any futher info from my lecturer. If you want any more example I may write it, I really appreciate your help

Comment: @BartoszWikiera: In the comments you said "where there is a path x->y->z then weight of the y =|xy -yz|". In the answer you said that the *edge weights* are absolute differences of *node values* (or it least it can be interpreted that way). Please clarify the question, format it better and add more useful examples.

Comment: @Niklas B. I updated question with example, please look at it

Comment: @BartoszWikiera: Your questions still fails to make it clear how the path weight is computed.

Comment: What is unclear ? Path weight for node is computed as absolute value of subtraction between weight of the edges for a node. Shortest path is a path including weights of those node

Comment: So if we want a path between neighbouring nodes we calculate the weight as the weight of the edge between the nodes. If we want a path between nodes that are not neighbours we use the absolute difference in edge weights? This implies that a path 1 -> 2 -> 3 can be shorter than the path 1 -> 2.

Comment: If path is made of two nodes the weight of the path is 0 (it's only case when formula doesn't work)

Comment: @BartoszWikiera: I edited the question. Let me know whether this is what you have in mind.

Comment: It's exactly what I meant. What do you think about the problem ? Is there a simple solution like modifying well-known algorithm or is it harder than that ?

Comment: @BartoszWikiera I think it's simple enough

Comment: @BartoszWikiera: You can use Dijkstra on edges instead of nodes and it will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Dijkstra on edges instead of nodes and it will work. Let `s` be the source node and `t` be the target. `w(i,j)` be the weight of the edge `(i,j)`.

```
d(i,j) = infinity for all edges (i,j)
q = new empty priority queue, ordered by d
for all edges (s,x):
    d(s,x) = 0
    insert (s,x) into q
while q is not empty:
    (x,y) = q.dequeue
    for all edges (y,z):
        if z != x and d(x,y) + |w(x,y) - w(y,z)| < d(y,z):
            d(y,z) = d(x,y) + |w(x,y) - w(y,z)|
            insert (y,z) into q
```

The result will be the minimum distance of an edge `(x,t)`. The runtime is `O(m * log m)` if the priority queue is implemented as a binary heap.

Answer (score -1):

To solve this kind of problem you can use a min/max flow type approach.

For every node you have two possible conditions: you either know fastest way to get to that node or you do not. So, you can tag each node with a number, or with null if it is unknown what the least cost is for that node.

In the beginning you only know the least cost for the nodes adjacent to the starting node, so you fill those in.

Now, propagating forwards you can find out the least cost for the nodes adjacent to those and so on, until you have filled in the whole graph.

Comment: The thing is that I don't really know the cost for the adjacents if I dont know the next nodes on the path. I need to know 3 nodes to compute the path weight.

Comment: Fine, then in that case you compute the minimums for each node TWO steps away from the starting node and propagate forwards from there. The principle is the same.

Comment: For any kind of problem like this, create a non-trivial example on paper and then manually fill in the minimums as you go. It's like sudoku. Once you have done it manually, it should be clear how to write a program to do it.

Comment: The cost of a node depends also on the edge you take next, so it's not sufficient to aggregate on path prefixes like in dijkstra. You simplify the problem to a degree where it has nothing to do with the original problem anymore and then you say without justification that it's simple to adapt totally unrelated ideas to the problem like max flow. I don't get how this is helpful. Have you thought this through?l

Comment: @Niklas B.Gah, it's Niklas again. First of all, for any graph where the test value is a combination of two edges you can convert the graph to a new graph where every edge in the new graph equates to a possible combination of edges in the original graph. So, you can certainly solve this problem by converting the graph and using Warshall. Secondly, the method I describe above will work perfectly well and is somewhat easier than doing the graph conversion. Neither of the methods has anything to do with the Djikstra algorithm.

Comment: @TylerDurden: I don't doubt that you know a method to solve this one, it's not hard to do. Still I can't extract from your answer even the slightest hint on how to actually do that. In fact what you describe *is* the Dijkstra algorithm, which you say yourself is unapplicable here. The key idea of transforming the graph is missing altogether. How max-flow has even remotely anything to do with this is beyond me. This answer is just misleading.

Comment: Tyler as I said in some previous comment, i need to know 3 nodes to compute path. Is it still appliable to your solution? I don't really see it

Comment: @Bartosz Wikiera If you are having difficulty understanding how to do it directly, I recommend converting the graph to a new one where the two-edge combination constraint is turned into a single edge and then using the Floyd-Warshall algorithm. E.g., if A->B = 3 and B->C = 1, then create an edge A->C = 2 in the new graph. Do this for every possible combination of 2 edges. The new graph will obviously be bigger than the old graph, but easier to analyze.

Comment: @Tyler that construction won't work for paths with more than 3 nodes

Comment: You guys aren't going to rest until I write this algorithm for you, are you?

Comment: @TylerDurden: Say the graph is `1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5` with `w(1,2) =  1, w(2,3) = 2, w(3,4) = 3, w(4,5) = 4`. Your algorithm would output `2` as the shortest path from `1` to `5`, which is impossible to achieve

Comment: And yes, generally answers on Stack Overflow should contain enough details that one can understand the idea behind it. You don't have to implement the algorithm, but pseudocode (even an informal natural-language description) is probably a reasonable minimum

Comment: I actually have an algorithm already that does almost what the OP wants, but I am not sure its worth the work to post it for a guy that has 1 reputation. Is it possible to have negative reputation?

Comment: @TylerDurden No you can't have negative rep. And it's kind of mean to discriminate new users on this site..

Comment: He's not a new user. His account is a year old. And he downvoted my answer, too.

Comment: No, I downvoted it, but I'm willing to upvote the answer if it's more complete

Comment: Pretty sure the original answer is wrong and does not even make sense what he described is basically Dijkstra algorithm it has nothing to do with max/min flow problem.  But in his comments he was right you can convert the graph but then after you convert graph you are still using Dijkstra. Plus you conversion is wrong. If A -> B = 3, B -> C = 1  you add a edge A -> B = 2, and after you did conversion you have to delete all the original edge to apply Dijkstra to the new graph, and you still need to reconstruct the original path, this gonna be very complicated to implement

Comment: @Linwei: It's not correct even when you delete the original edges. You can see that if you check out what happens for paths of length > 3

Comment: I can not see why it would be incorrect, could you give me a example.

Comment: @Linwei: Please read my comment above that begins with "Say the graph is..."

Comment: @Niklas B. I did read your comment, but that is irrelevant, his conversion is wrong.